# How to create a low CPU usages cron jobs in php

Tags: php, jobs

I'm create a cron jobs for sending job alert to facebook messenger subscriber. But when it run my website server CPU usages take 100%. 
Please see this attached picture

[image]

I'm wrote the following code for sending massage to the FaceBook Messenger subscriber. My cron jobs will run after 5 minutes interval.

```
  <?php
require_once "btm-config.php";
proc_nice(10);

    $select_os_job = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM subscriber");


    if($select_os_job->num_rows > 0) {
        while($os_job = $select_os_job->fetch_assoc()) {

        $job_id = $os_job['id'];    
            $edu = array(
                    "u_secondary"=>$os_job['u_secondary'],
                    "secondary"=>$os_job['secondary'],
                    "h_secondary"=>$os_job['h_secondary'],
                    "diploma"=>$os_job['diploma'],
                    "bachelor_honors"=>$os_job['bachelor_honors'],
                    "master"=>$os_job['master']
                    );
            //print_r($edu);
            $edu_active = "";
            foreach($edu as $edu_name => $edu_status) {
                if($edu_status == "1") {
                    $edu_active .= $edu_name."=".$edu_status." OR ";
                }
            }
            $edu_active = rtrim($edu_active,"OR ");



            $select_ja_users = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM msnUsers WHERE status='1' AND ($edu_active)");

                if($select_ja_users->num_rows > 0) {
                $cj_count = 1;
                while($ja_users = $select_ja_users->fetch_assoc()) {

                    $mgn_id = $ja_users['msn_id'];

                    $msn = "Massage";

                    //Now send job to relavants subscriber in fb messenger
                    $botman->say($msn, $mgn_id);
                    usleep(100000);
                    if($cj_count == 1) {
                        // update data as sended
                        $dbcon->query("UPDATE submit_msn SET msnStatus=3 WHERE id='$job_id'");
                        $cj_count = $cj_count+1;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Please give some advise for solve this problem. 
thanks

Comment: well, that's basically the desired behavior: do the tasks as fast as possible. to reduce (average) CPU usage, you have to slow down your code - most quickly achieved by `usleep()`. just wait a few milliseconds every iteration and let the CPU do nothing.

Comment: Hello Franz Gleichmann, Actually I have total 2000+ subscriber. i need to send them the alert quickly (As Soon As possible). Currently it takes almost 10 minutes. If I use usleep(1000000) or sleep(1) it will take a long time. So, what can I do? please give me some suggestions. thanks.

Comment: you don't have to sleep a whole second. i said *a few milliseconds*.  try 10ms, for example. at 2000 subscribers that should increase your time by not even half a minute. but if you **do** need to send the alerts ASAP - then just live with the CPU load and/or upgrade your server. also: you should try optimizing your code & queries - which is out of the scope for SO. but on first glance, it seems very inefficient.

Comment: Hello, recently i took a VPS for solving the problem. My main domain ([echakri.net](https://echakri.net/)) hosted in a SSD shared hosting and I create a sub domain which are hosted in VPS. But when I run the cron job from VPS my main domain not working. It says: **Resources Limit is reached**
But CPU usage below of 10% and Entry Process below of 5 in shared hosting. What is the Problem?